Identify and substitute f1404zs
I need help understanding which chip I need to buy.
First, I hope this is the correct community; if not, I apologize.
My intention is to repair a Mark Levinson 86280-0w690 audio amplifier, inside which a chip has exploded...
On the chip, I read the following three markings:

F1404ZS P249D D1YD

Below is a photo of the exploded chip (on the right):

I can't find the specifications for this chip (a MOSFET)? And possibly which replacements to buy in Europe.
What can I buy to substitute this damaged Chip?

I believe this is International Rectifiers F1404ZS.  Available from major distributors without difficulty.
Just noting that one way to start is to try to identify the manufacturer from a logo database.  Then it gets a lot easier.

From linked datasheet.
